# In excel how to make union mapping between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't know the term to describe the situation so just make it up

basically for example there are two columns

```
  Col A      Col B
----------------------
| date 1 | 2020-02-03|
| date 2 | 2020-03-12|
| date 3 | 2020-04-25|
======================
```

I'd like to have a function to generate following results

```
      Col C
----------------------
| date 1 = 2020-02-03|
| date 1 = 2020-03-12|
| date 1 = 2020-04-25|
| date 2 = 2020-02-03|
| date 2 = 2020-03-12|
| date 2 = 2020-04-25|
| date 3 = 2020-02-03|
| date 3 = 2020-03-12|
| date 3 = 2020-04-25|
======================
```

it's like concat union of each row from both column values but allow to add extra string (`=` for example).

Comment: This is like the SQL cross join or cartesian product, if you want to give it a name https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

Comment: I'm thinking VBA would probably be best for this because a formula is going to get pretty hairy.. like if this data starts on row 1, then in column c a formula like `=INDIRECT("A" & MOD(ROW(), COUNTA(A:A)) + 1 ) & " = " & INDIRECT("B" & ROUND((ROW()+1)/COUNTA(A:A), 0))` would work... which is a nightmare to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your first table as follows, i.e. add column headers. (this is my existing code, which requires column header. Too lazy to modify it, so, please follow)

[image]

Change the value of `paraVal` in below `Sub` to be the range of your first table (including the headers) and run it. The combination will be generated below your first table (so, make sure there's sufficient space for the result). Combine the resulted columns by your own way (e.g. `TEXTJOIN`, `CONCAT`...)

```
Sub CombinationTable()

    Dim paraVal As Range
    Dim paraInfo() As Long
    Dim rowTtl As Long
    Dim colIdx As Long
    Dim repIdx As Long
    Dim colIdxG As Long
    Dim rowIdxG As Long
    Dim rowStartG As Long
    Dim rowEndG As Long
    Dim colCell1 As Range
    Dim colCellN As Range
    Dim repeat As Range

    Set paraVal = Range("F4", "G7")


    On Error GoTo 0
    With paraVal

        rowTtl = 1
        ReDim paraInfo(1 To .Columns.Count)
        For colIdx = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(.Rows.Count - 1, colIdx)) Then  ' .rows.count-1 = 1st value
                paraInfo(colIdx) = 0
            Else
                Set colCellN = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIdx)
                Set colCell1 = colCellN.End(xlUp)
                paraInfo(colIdx) = colCellN.Row - colCell1.Row  ' no +1 bcoz last row is header, not value
                rowTtl = rowTtl * paraInfo(colIdx)
            End If
        Next colIdx

        rowStartG = .Row + .Rows.Count
        rowEndG = rowStartG + rowTtl - 1

        For colIdx = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If paraInfo(colIdx) > 0 Then
                rowTtl = rowTtl / paraInfo(colIdx)
                rowIdxG = rowStartG
                colIdxG = .Columns(colIdx).Column
                Set colCellN = .Columns(colIdx).Cells(.Columns(colIdx).Rows.Count).Offset(-paraInfo(colIdx)).Resize(paraInfo(colIdx))
                For Each colCell1 In colCellN.Cells
                    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIdxG, colIdxG), ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIdxG + rowTtl - 1, colIdxG)).Value = colCell1.Value
                    rowIdxG = rowIdxG + rowTtl
                Next colCell1
                Set repeat = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(rowStartG, colIdxG), ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIdxG - 1, colIdxG))

                If colIdx > 1 Then
                    repeat.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIdxG, colIdxG), ActiveSheet.Cells(rowEndG, colIdxG))
                End If
            End If
        Next colIdx

    End With
End Sub
```